# NPM ERR - npm install cap/pcap

Tags: node.js, npm, wireshark, pcap, libpcap

I have an error when I try to npm install  cap/pcap or any other nodejs library of the same style.

However I have visual studio, python, npcap installed on my pc

I'm on windows 11, does anyone know where this could come from?

I use node v16.14.2

```
code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\arnau\Desktop\Test-albion\node_modules\cap
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Les projets sont g�n�r�s individuellement dans cette solution. Pour activer la g�n�ration en parall�le, ajoutez le commutateur "-m".
npm ERR!   binding.cc
npm ERR!   win_delay_load_hook.cc
npm ERR! C:\\Users\\arnau\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.14.2\\x64\\node.lib : fatal error LNK1127: biblioth�que endommag�e [C:\Users\arnau\Desktop\Test-albion\node_modules\cap\build\cap.vcxproj]     
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.10 found at "C:\Users\arnau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.33423.256) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\arnau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\arnau\\Desktop\\Test-albion\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\arnau\\Desktop\\Test-albion\\node_modules\\cap\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\arnau\\Desktop\\Test-albion\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\arnau\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.14.2\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\arnau\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.14.2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\arnau\\Desktop\\Test-albion\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\arnau\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.14.2\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\arnau\\Desktop\\Test-albion\\node_modules\\cap',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\arnau\\Desktop\\Test-albion\\node_modules\\cap\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\arnau\Desktop\Test-albion\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\arnau\\Desktop\\Test-albion\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\arnau\Desktop\Test-albion\node_modules\cap
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\arnau\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-23T12_32_58_459Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to install all the tools of visual studio 2019, to change my version of python but it did not work